# JavaScript-Event not only on first element

Tags: javascript

I have the following wonderful piece of code. As you can see it is a function to open/close (show/hide) a box of content on button click.

Now this works just perfectly fine. But only on the first button/box … if there are MANY (and there are many), it does not work. It only works on the first one.

I know I could do this all pretty easily with jQuery — BUT my goal here is to use vanilla JavaScript and not to be dependent on jQuery.

So how should I edit the code to work on MANY buttons/boxes — all with vanilla Javascript?

(Look at it as a learning-piece for me to skip jQuery.)

```
<button class="openUrls" data-thisButton="openUrls--{ID}" data-target="js-urls--{ID}" data-state="closed"><svg… />Collapse</button>

<div class="urls js-urls--{ID}" data-state="closed">Content</div>

<style>
.urls[data-state='closed'] {display:none}
.urls[data-state='open'] {display:inherit}
.openUrls[data-state='open'] svg {transform:rotate(180deg)} // rotates the carret-SVG inside the button-element
</style>

<script>
var button = document.querySelector('.openUrls');

var toggleState = function(elem,class1,class2) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
  elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === class1 ? class2 : class1);
};

button.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = button.getAttribute('data-target');
  toggleState('.'+target, 'closed', 'open');

  var thisButton = this.getAttribute('data-thisButton');
  toggleState('[data-thisButton='+thisButton+']', 'closed', 'open');
};
</script>
```

**Update:** Live-Demo https://jsfiddle.net/b24ybtjv/3/

Comment: I'm not following this... did you try `querySelectorAll`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `document.querySelector()`: _"Returns the **first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors."_

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Yes, if I use `querySelectorAll` nothing happens at all. With `querySelector` it at least works with the first element.

Comment: Update: I've added a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `querySelectorAll` then loop

```js
var toggleState = function(elem,class1,class2) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
  elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === class1 ? class2 : class1);
};

var button = document.querySelectorAll('.openUrls');

button.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    console.log(target);
    toggleState('.' + target, 'closed', 'open');

    var thisButton = this.getAttribute('data-thisButton');
    toggleState('[data-thisButton=' + thisButton + ']', 'closed', 'open');
  }
});
```

```css
.urls[data-state='closed'] {display:none}
.urls[data-state='open'] {display:inherit}
.openUrls[data-state='open'] svg {transform:rotate(180deg)} // rotates the carret-SVG inside the button-element
```

```html
<button class="openUrls" data-thisButton="openUrls-1" data-target="js-urls-1" data-state="closed"><svg… />Collapse</button>
<button class="openUrls" data-thisButton="openUrls-2" data-target="js-urls-2" data-state="closed"><svg… />Collapse 2</button>

<div class="urls js-urls-1" data-state="closed">Content</div>
<div class="urls js-urls-2" data-state="closed">Content2</div>
```

Comment: This is why Me and JavaScript is a Love/Hate Story :-) … sometimes the solution is so easy and close! THANK YOU, @ewwink !

Comment: @Andreas my bad habit :lol updated the answer, albuvee you're welcome